# grunt build production issue angularjs

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have been using grunt for many projects. But this project I have encountered an issue.

I have successfully ran grunt build. My application has login functionality and I use $cookieStore to store and retrieve data to keep user logged in. In production when I refresh the page I am getting logged out. This issue happens only in production.

I couldn't sort out this issue as the minified file is too large and encrypted.

Comment: i used $timeout function and it helped me solve the issue. Hence closing the issue.